# Alert Center API Scope issue

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-alerts, google-alert-center-api

According to the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/rest/v1beta1/TopLevel/getSettings#authorization-scopes

And Also the discovery Documents:
https://alertcenter.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta1

The scope for "Alert Center API" is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts

However, when I use this scope,  I get the error message:

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_scope
Some requested scopes cannot be shown: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts]
```

Did the scope change and the documentation is outdated? Any other options to access this API?

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample code with no senstive data that I can reproduce to obtain that error message ? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi @mateorandwolf, I tested the scope in google path playground. I haven't written code yet. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/. The scope is not in the list but you can add it at the end of the list in a text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response is happening because you are not using the scope with a service account. As described by [this piece of documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/guides#use_alert_center_api):

> Your project must use a service account when accessing the API.

Therefore, if you access this API with a service account you will be able to interface it correctly, otherwise, you won't. More about service account authorization [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

Also, note that the scope **is** in the list under `G Suite Alert Center API v1beta1`.